# Правильно построить замыкание

Tags: node.js, javascript, redis, замыкания

Создаю некоторый класс, который при инициализации получает список ключей полей и должен принять из базы редис по этим ключам некоторые данные, которые надлежит хранить в классе до его отработки. Делаю так:

```
heap =  function(arr) { 
        var self = this;
        this.list = {};

        for(var key in arr){
             clientRedis.hgetall("heap:"+arr[key], function(err,obj){
                 (function(i){
                     self.list[i] = obj;
                 })(arr[key]);
             });
        }
};
```

Однако, после создания `new heap(data)` в `heap.list` сидит один объект -- последний из обрабатываемых. Где я ошибся в построении функции замыкания?..

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ:функции вызова методов библиотеки `clientRedis` -- асинхронные, может мне коллбек нужен вместе с замыканием?

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, откуда берется i?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

внимание, правильный ответ!

```
heap =  function(arr) { 
    var self = this;
    this.list = {};

    for(var key in arr){
         (function(i) {
             clientRedis.hgetall("heap:"+i, function(err,obj){
                 self.list[i] = obj;
             });
         })(arr[key]);
    }
};
```

т.е., одеть в функцию-анонимку нужно было всю логику, теперь все ОК, создаются все объекты. ВСем спасибо за внимание!

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(arg){

}(my_arg));
```

Так понятнее? =)

Если я все правильно понимаю, то закрывающая скобка у вас не на месте. Соответственно, i у вас всегда 0, оно не задается через my_arg, который у вас arr[key]

Comment: исправил синтаксис, но объект все также остается один, - добавляю некоторое уточнение в свой вопрос. и, кстати, - конструкция (function(a){...})(b) также имеет право на существование, судя по манускриптам..